# Is virtual memory used everywhere in current OS?

Tags: operating-system, virtual-memory

I basically understand how virtual memory works but I'm wondering whether there are some situations where virtual memory is not used, especially for kernel address space.

Thanks!

Comment: Fell free to upvote the answers you find useful

Answer (score 1):

Only on older systems, I don't think that most current systems don't use it (unless it's a very specific device where all the functionality is in kernel context).

Comment: Relating to kernel, what processes could possibly not use virtual memory?

Comment: @ethanjyx All processes can use virtual memory even the kernel itself. The only time this is sort of bypassed is in kernel space for quick allocations so that accesses don't require page table lookups and just use offsets instead.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, with [reference](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2160852/en-us):

> In modern operating systems such as Windows, applications and many
>   system processes always reference memory by using virtual memory
>   addresses. Virtual memory addresses are automatically translated to
>   real (RAM) addresses by the hardware. Only core parts of the operating
>   system kernel bypass this address translation and use real memory
>   addresses directly.
>
> Virtual memory is always being used, even when the memory that is
>   required by all running processes does not exceed the volume of RAM
>   that is installed on the system.